# Can an adverb precede modal verb?

Tags: adverbs

Can an adverb precede modal verb? I've seen this kind of sentence:
**I just can't believe what happened**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a grammatically correct construction.

The problem is that *semantically* it rarely makes sense (verbs like *can*, *should*, etc. don't really have any qualities that could be modified by an adverb), and the only example I can think of is using it for added emphasis:

> I simply can't understand why you did it.
>
> I really shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Can I emphasize a modal with "do"? Like that: "I do can read."?

Comment: @BoSsYyY not really, it sounds very off to me. Emphatic "do" should be followed by an infinitive, and "can" along with most auxiliaries doesn't have an infinitive form.

Comment: I don't know why you say *verbs like **can, should**, etc. don't really have any qualities that could be modified by an adverb*. Fairly obviously it makes sense to understand ***just** = simply (= "really")* in *I just can't believe it!* as modifying ***can***. You've only got to consider the implications of shifting the adverb to the right, so it modifies ***believe*** instead. That would give us *I can't just believe it*, which would have a completely different meaning (where ***just = merely***). Perhaps asserting that mere belief is insufficient (maybe he needs to *prove* it for himself).